# How do I connect the commands

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So, this is my first script ever and I'm not an programmer. Infact, im an 15 year old student, so dont expect much from me, but I need to write a script to create a new User in an AD. And I just cant connect these two command. I want to connect the SamAccountName and the UserPrincipalName into one popup.[this is my "code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSVvK.png) Btw. im using PowerShell, if this gives u any information

Comment: You show only a tiny fragment of your code in an image.. Please [edit] your question and put the entire code you have in there as [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text. Also, it looks like you want to use `Read-Host` to get **two** vital names for the new user, but then you need to explain why you want to combine that input, how you intend to split that into the two properties and last but not least: how you want to check if the user typing that info does not write bogus names.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlet from the ActiveDirectory module.

So if you're looking to create this using `SamAccountName` and `UserPrincipalName` it would look something like:

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $SANInput -UserPrincipalName $UPNInput
```